# What is the difference between download, progressive-download, streaming and pseudo-streaming

Tags: video, download, streaming, video-streaming, mp4

Let me put my understanding first, lets say we are referring to a video file.

**download** => In general download, file cannot be played unless it completely downloaded.

**progressive-download** => Here, we download data in chunks. Chunks are downloaded(cached) into some local directory which is session specific, and can be played even while following chunks are being downloaded.

**streaming** => Its more like a radio/TV, Where the buffer data is cached/stored/downloaded in the RAM, and the new data keeps replacing the buffer data.

**pseudo-streaming** => sounds similar like progressive download, couldn't visualize differently.

Please help my understanding.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_download

Comment: Just google those terms with "vs" in between. Then come back if you have any more questions.